# Eigen:: Cast sparse matrix as, specifically, row order or col order

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, eigen

I have in a function internal,

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> & M;

if (M.IsRowMajor)
     return my_func_template<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::RowMajor>&>(M,M.rows());
```

However, this does not compile, as the compiler does not believe `M` is an `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::RowMajor>`.  How do I cast my reference as, specifically, `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::RowMajor>`, in the type-safe environment of C++11?

---

For example:

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Smat;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::RowMajor> RMSmat;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::ColMajor> CMSmat;    

enum direction { row, col};

template<class Mat>
vector<double> sum_along_inner(Mat &M){
    vector<double> sums(M.innerSize(),0);
    for(auto i = 0; i < M.outerSize(); i++){
        for(typename M::InnerIterator it(M,i); it;++it){
            sums[i] += it.value();
        }
    }
}
vector<double> sum_along_axis(Smat &M, direction dir){

    // If I could solve this problem, 
    // 
    // I could also function off these if components, 
    // and re-use them for other order-dependent functions I write
    // so that my top level functions are only about 2-4 lines long

    if(dir == direction::row){
        if(M.IsRowMajor)
            return sum_along_inner<RMSmat>((my question) M);

        //else
        RMsmat Mrowmajor = M;
        return sum_along_inner<RMSmat>(Mrowmajor);
    }
    else { 
       if(!M.IsRowMajor)
            return sum_along_inner<CMSmat>(M);

       // else
       CMSmat Mcolmajor = M;
       return sum_along_inner<CMSmat>((my_question) Mcolmajor);
    }
}
```

And if I do more than just `sum_along_axis`, then the code complexity in terms of number of lines, readability, etc. is double what it needs to be **if only I could solve this problem that I am asking about**.

Otherwise, I can't abstract the loop, and I have to repeat it for column major and row major...because I can't just assume I wont call `sum_along_axis` from a function that hasn't already swapped the major-order from the default `Eigen::ColMajor` to `Eigen::RowMajor`...

Further, if I am operating at the order of mb-sized sparse matrices with dimensions too unwieldy to represent in dense matrix form, I am going to notice a major slowdown (which defeats the purpose of using a sparse matrix to begin with) if I don't write **composable** functions which are **order agnostic**, and transition the major-order only when needed.

So, unless I solve for this, my line count and/or function count, more or less, starts to go combinatorial.

Comment: No idea what you actually want to achieve here. But in your example, `M.IsRowMajor` will always be false.

Comment: @chtz ah, ok.  So in order to do any functions of a general Sparse Matrix double, I need to make two versions—one for row major and one for col major?  For example, I want to run a reduction to a vector down rows or cols... and I may be dealing with either a row major or col major sparse matrix, depending on what I am doing in the outer scope

Comment: @chtz basically, I am trying to avoid repetitive code

Comment: Could you post something like a [mcve] of what you want to do? I don't see any reason why you need to cast anything, nor do I see where you need to implement two functions.

Comment: @chtz updated with the example you needed to motivate the answer

Comment: why `M` is a reference type: `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> & M;` and doesn't have assignment? This has no sense so that is why compiler complains (or you didn't show proper code). A reference is like a const pointer to a type which has warranty to be NOT `null` (have to have an assignment).

Comment: @MarekR I have already written working code that has an assignment exactly like I have written, so I don't know what compiler you are using that does not allow this. (I am using clang).  This is the code where I have written specific functions for both the row and col major case...I would like to collapse the code, but I can't on account of my question.  Alternatively, I can write a pointer version.

Comment: @MarekR however, the problem will occur if my typedefs were to change to reference types... could that be what you are thinking about? Assigning a ref type to a ref type? anyways, that isn't occurring here.

Comment: I think @MarekR referred to your first 3-line code snippet (which is indeed incomplete). Please remove the pointer variant of your code, it does not add anything to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my first comment `M.IsRowMajor` will always be false. This is because `Eigen::SparseMatrix` has always two template arguments, where the second defaults to `Eigen::ColMajor`

If you want to write a function which accepts both row- and column-major matrices, you need to write something like

```
template<int mode>
vector<double> sum_along_axis(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,mode> const &M, direction dir)
    if(dir == direction::row){
        return sum_along_inner<RMSmat>(M); // implicit conversion if necessary
    }
    else { 
        return sum_along_inner<CMSmat>(M); // implicit conversion if necessary
    }
}
```

You need to rewrite `sum_along_inner` to accept a const reference to make the implicit conversion work:

```
template<class Mat>
vector<double> sum_along_inner(Mat const &M){
    vector<double> sums(M.outerSize(),0); // sums needs to have size M.outerSize()
    for(auto i = 0; i < M.outerSize(); i++){
        for(typename M::InnerIterator it(M,i); it;++it){
            sums[i] += it.value();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the conversion from row- to column-major (and vice versa) you should write a function which sums along the outer dimension and decide in your main function which function to call.